# how to show all raw on a google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have created a brand new spreadsheet on googlesheet, and then I shared it with about 10 people.
After a while, we find out that there are some row that are hidden, and probably protected by one of the other account.

[image]

so I tryied :

1- select all the row and then clic "unhide"

2- resize all the line (just in case...)

3- "show protected row"

[image]

but it didn't change anything

I exactly know whodidi the modification and when it went.
[image]

but that person told me that she didn't do it on purpose. And when I use her account, I'am not able to unlock or unhide it !

any Idea ?

Comment: Is it hidden or filtered? If filtered then just do infilter it.

Comment: so apparently it was "filtered", which is a "function" that I don't use/know... But I solve it with `spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().remove();` and then it works ! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The light green row number bar in the screenshot indicates that there is an active filter. The funnel icon in the label of column `N` also reveals that the sheet is filtered by column `N`.

To remove the filter and show all the rows, choose **Data > Remove filter**.